# typeahead.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead

I looked through all the other `'length' of null` questions, but they didn't help me.

I am on a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4F6Kcbo3Vw) tutorial to implement autosuggest into a form using typeahead.js, but it isn't working. Chromes console puts out:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

Could someone please help me and point out where I am wrong.

Here the relevant html:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="user" id="users">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/typeahead.js"></script>
<script src="js/global.js"></script>
```

and the relevant js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var users = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('username'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: 'users.php?query=%QUERY'
    });

users.initialize(); 

    $('#users').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        //minLength: 2          
    }, {
        name: 'users',
        displayKey: 'username',
        source: users.ttAdapter()   // what is ttAdapter() ?
    });
});
```

[image: "Uncaught TypeError" in Chromes Console]

Comment: where is the error thrown?

Comment: @CodeiSir Edited my post with a screenshot of Chromes Console

Comment: Use the Chrome web inspector to see what is being sent to and from the server.

Comment: @user2182349 Web inspector isn't showing its magnifying glass when hovering over the input field nor over the button. Sorry, using it for the first time, but it should be pretty straightforward?! Point me in the right direction if am doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the YouTube tutorial comments, someone pointed this out:

> Worked for me when i replaced:

`remote: 'users.php?query=%QUERY'`

> with:

```
remote: {
    url: 'users.php?query=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
}
```

Now it works.